# zxing intent "google goggles" doesn't recognize barcodes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, zxing, google-goggles

I've made a little App for android with Zxing Intent, but it has a problem, because google goggles receives the Intent and do nothing, because it's not capable of decoding barcodes. Is there a way to restrict google goggles, but not other Barcode  scanners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Goggles does decode barcodes. Which Intent?
You can restrict to Barcode Scanner by calling `Intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android")` though this would also exclude apps like [Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android).

The better solution is to use the [`IntentIntegrator`](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) code supplied from the project. There you can supply the names of packages you want to include, and could use `TARGET_ALL_KNOWN` minus the Goggles packages if you wanted.